# What are these extra 11 dimensions of human mind?

Tags: consciousness, psychophysics

I posted this question on the physics stack exchange, but I was guided to ask the question here though from the view point of a neuro-scientist which should be more useful if she has already followed the general current of changes in Theoretical physics:

Recently I faced a research result showing the brain works in 11 dimensions. I was wondering if these dimensions have anything possible to do with those of M-theory?

They use algebraic topology techniques to come up with their result.

In string theory there are 3+1+6+1 dimensions, space+time+compactified dimensions+extended dimension on the strings(strings change into branes)

[Cliques of Neurons Bound into Cavities Provide a Missing Link between Structure and Function](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fncom.2017.00048/full)

Comment: What’s most fascinating is that in this research they determined that the brain creates temporary dimensions to complete whatever task. Neurons are incredible but let’s face it, it’s the fundamental quantum aspects that drive these capabilities. We have so much to figure out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no relationship to string theory.

You might imagine brain activity as taking place in an N-dimensional space, where N is the number of neurons in the brain. However, neurons aren't independent of each other, so there aren't really N unique dimensions. Using various dimensionality reduction techniques, for example principle component analysis, you can choose to discard some dimensions that have less variance and if you set some threshold you can say "well really there are X dimensions of brain activity". Of course that number is dependent on the threshold you choose.

The actual meaning of those dimensions varies by the approach taken, but here I think the closest would be that the 11 dimensions represent different functional networks in the brain doing different things. Functional meaning they do similar things at the same time.

Other people get different numbers so 11 is just their particular result, there's nothing special or consistent about 11.